# Using Lizmap plugin with QGIS Server to manage user roles

Tags: qgis-server, lizmap

I want to manage user roles in server side but I found out that QGIS Server does not have this option so Lizmap may be a solution. Can I use Lizmap plugin with QGIS but not to use the Lizmap web client because I want a personalized interface?

Comment: Can you precise what is your purpose ? Do you just need WMS/WFS functionnalities ?

Comment: yes exactly ! @NicolasBoisteault

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the server part of Lizmap alone which enhance QGIS Server (you can create a WMTS service with caches tiles for example).

You can also manage user roles with the back-office as written in the [doc](https://docs.3liz.com/en/introduction.html#configuring-with-the-web-back-office).